# How can pd.cut return a number as group?

Tags: pandas

## Example

```
pd.cut(df['a'],[0,2,4,10,np.inf],right=False)
```

It returns `[0,2),[2,4),[4,10),[10,np.inf)` .

But how can I get `[0],(0,2),[2,4),[4,10),[10,np.inf)`?

Comment: Can you please share a sample of `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all values are integers and greater than zero, this could work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]})
pd.cut(df['a'], [-np.inf, 1, 2, 4, 10, np.inf], right=False)
```